# Insert special mini bibliography elsewhere in the document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In a document that already has a bibliography, occasionally I need to insert information about a book elsewhere in the latex file. To save typing out information in the book elsewhere in my document, is there another way to do it? i.e. I want to do basically this:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{works-cited.bib}

....

In this chapter, you will need to have already purchased and reflected upon:

\specialbibliography{book1, book2}

Having read that book, now we can move on to consider...
```

Comment: Using `bibtex` it might work with `multibib.sty`. But I guess (although I'm not very familiar with it) it is much easier with `biblatex`.

Comment: @PatrickHappel Ok, cool, I don't know what the difference is anyway. I am using something called `biber` I have added that to the question.

Comment: There are several ways to do this: bibfilters, print by (not) entry type, print by (not) keyword, print by (not) category, etc. There is also the command `\fullcite`, which (if defined for `style=sbl`) will print the 'full' citation information.  Here are the results for the search "[biblatex multiple bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=biblatex+multiple+bibliography)". Without more information about your specific needs, this seems to be, generically, a duplicate of many questions.

Comment: `stlye=sbl` does support `fullcite`, but it won't print it using the bibliography style, it will use the first citation style. (I'm the author of `biblatex-sbl`). `biblatex` is pretty flexible and `biblatex-sbl` should be able to do anything that the standard styles can do (if not, I'll fix it). I'll have a think and post an answer if not one else does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution showing both usage of the `refsegment` environment and the `\fullcite` command. Note the different output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{talbert:1992,
  author = {Talbert, Charles H.},
  title = {Reading John: A Literary and Theological Commentary on the Fourth Gospel and the Johannine Epistles},
  location = {New York},
  publisher = {Crossroad},
  date = {1992}
}
@book{robinson+koester:1971,
  author = {Robinson, James M. and Koester, Helmut},
  title = {Trajectories through Early Christianity},
  location = {Philadelphia},
  publisher = {Fortress},
  date = {1971}
}
@book{scott+etal:1993,
  author = {Scott, Bernard Brandon and Dean, Margaret and Sparks, Kristen and LaZar, Frances},
  title = {Reading New Testament Greek},
  location = {Peabody, MA},
  publisher = {Hendrickson},
  date = {1993}
}
@book{egger:1996,
  author = {Egger, Wilhelm},
  title = {How to Read the New Testament: An Introduction to Linguistic and Historical-Critical Methodology},
  shorttitle = {How to Read},
  translator = {Heinegg, Peter},
  location = {Peabody, MA},
  publisher = {Hendrickson},
  date = {1996}
}
@book{wellhausen:1883,
  author = {Wellhausen, Julius},
  title = {Prolegomena zur Geschichte Israels},
  edition = {2},
  location = {Berlin},
  publisher = {Reimer},
  date = {1883}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}

In this chapter, you will need to have already purchased and reflected upon:

\begin{refsegment}
  \nocite{talbert:1992,robinson+koester:1971}
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=none]
\end{refsegment}

\subsection*{Or using \texttt{\textbackslash fullcite}:}

\hspace{\parindent}\fullcite{robinson+koester:1971}.

\fullcite{talbert:1992}.

\section*{Section 2}

Having read that book, now we can move on to consider...

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the 'special bibliography' is to be kept separate from the rest, one would use `refsection` instead of `refsegment`. It probably does not matter a great deal which you choose, but there are differences in certain situations.